# How to get a dynamically changing NSTableView in OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

I am new to coding for Mac. I am familiar with UITableView's from iOS coding, but can't seem to get NSTableView to work properly on my app. Yes I have looked through documentation and tutorials, but I am having trouble getting the result I need. My desired outcome should be pretty basic and simple, but I am stumped on the TableViews. I would really like it to function more like how it does with a UITableView rather than how it seems to want to function with NSTableView. I don't want to add or remove rows. I only need 1 column and I would really like for it to work like a list of buttons that can be pressed and trigger the content associated with that option on the same screen on the next NSView over.

(I have 3 views on one screen. The first is the main menu to the left and when pressed triggers the tableView to display the submenu. When that option is selected it opens the content on the far right of the screen. My desired result anyways.)

Currently nothing is populating the tableview. This is what it currently looks like.

.h

```
@interface RootViewController : NSViewController <NSTableViewDataSource>{
IBOutlet NSView *mainMenuView;
IBOutlet NSTableView *tableView;
NSMutableArray *options;

}

-(IBAction)mainMenuBtn:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m

```
@interface RootViewController ()

@end

@implementation RootViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        options = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad{

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView{
    return [options count];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
    return [[options objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:[tableColumn identifier]];
}

-(IBAction)mainMenuBtn:(id)sender{
    NSLog(@"1");
    [options addObject:@"Strain 1"];
    NSString *test = [options objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(test);
    [tableView reloadData];

}
```

Currently I have tableView connected in the NIB to the TableView. I attempted to connect dataSource to File's Owner, but that didn't work. Can't seem to find any place else to hook it up too. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First the dataSource of the NSTableView must be connected to your RootViewController instance in Interface Builder, or through code.
Something that seems a little suspicious to me is the line:

```
return [[options objectAtIndex:row] valueForKey:[tableColumn identifier]];
```

I don't know what is the value for the [tableColumn identifier] but it must match the property of the objects you're adding to your array. I can see that the objects you're adding are strings, so [tableColumn identifier] must be a property of class NSString. If you're using a string as the array's object, try using this:

```
return [options objectAtIndex:row];
```

Comment: Well I made the adjustments you suggested. That first return was something from a tutorial, but I replaced it as you suggested. I also added [options addObject:@"Strain 1"]; to where the MutableArray alloc is so I could verify the table will display content. It works, but still when the button is pressed the table isn't updating as you would expect. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Are the four first lines of mainMenuBtn working?... specifically NSLog(test)... ?

Comment: Yea actually I think I figured out what is going on, but not sure how to fix it. In the numberOfRows I added an NSLog to display count. When the reload happens it calls it again, but the count stays at 1. Even though in the mainMenuBtn I have the same NSLog (which happens prior) and it states there are 2. Not quite sure what is happening in between.